# Can't find Report folder to see the error log

Tags: error, install

I've just uploaded the Magento files to my server and just gave the proper permissions to folders... but I'm getting an error before the install.
I know that I have to look for the error at the report folder that it's inside var folder, but it isn't even created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment `ini_set("display_errors",1);` inside your `index.php` file and try again.  It will give you the php error if there is one.

Comment: I've uncommented but still showing me the error log number.

Comment: Run the Magento Compatibility Checker to ensure that you have everything needed to use Magento on your server. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Comment: The free web server that I was using that has many issues... I gave up and tried a VirtualBox installation... it worked

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your reports aren't being written without knowing more about your environment, but you could try using developer mode so that the errors are printed to the screen.

You need to call Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); in your index.php file to do this you could either set $_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] in your server environment or simply uncomment the check:

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
```

also display the errors by using ini_set('display_errors', 1);